# How to get a file/folder type in C#?

Tags: c#

I was thinking of making a more "advanced" version of `System.IO.Path`, `System.IO.File` & `System.IO.Directory`.

Obviously I started with `System.IO.Path`, because the base for File and Directory will be Path, I started writing a function named `ContainsInvalidChars` (checks to see if said path contains invalid characters), for this I had to use `GetDirectoryName` & `GetFileName` but, after writing these 2 methods I stopped and thought to myself:

How do these 2 methods distinguish between the input path being a directory, file or dir + file". I ran a couple of tests and found that they don't. For example, if you had something like `C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData` and you were to put this into `GetFileName` it would return `AppData` even tho `AppData` is a folder and technically should be part of the directory and file name should be null, same with `GetDirectoryName`, even tho `AppData` is part of the directory name it only returns `C:\\Users\\UserName`. So I came to the conclusion that I will first have to write a proper `GetFileName` & `GetDirectoryName` methods and then only write `ContainsInvalidChars`. The question still stands, how do I distinguish between the 3 types of path. While thinking about this I started looking for a couple file on my computer when I noticed (something that's easily ignored) the `Type` column where it shows the type of file/folder, if folder then `File folder` if file (even without extension) `(Ext) File` so, here I am. Is there any way to get the file/folder type in C#?

I know that at the end of the day you could always write `C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\` and yes, this will be DIR="C:\Users\UserName\AppData" & FILE="" but i know some don't write `\\` at the end and just write `C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData`.

Comment: There should be a way to check from command line which you can use from the code

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `GetFileName`? What do you think it does? Do you think it actually **looks** at the file system?

Comment: will have a read, probably should of done that in the first place xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.IO` provided functions:
`File.Exists(string Path)` and `Directory.Exists(string Path)` . Returns boolean value based on value of Path

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\"))
    Console.WriteLine("Folder exists");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Path might be of file");


Ouput:
   Folder exists
```

Comment: That's true, now that i think about it, that's probably the only way to distinguish between 'em. Luckily you can't create folders named the same as files (and vise versa) so that's also a plus because, if you could create folders named the same as files then the question would still stand.

Comment: I did not understand what exactly you are saying, can you please put your thoughts in simple words

Comment: Or the path could be nothing totally. No file nor folder. In such a case you are still showing it *might* be a file

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net 4.0 and above then there is one way to do this by using below code.

```
File.GetAttributes("your path to directory or file").HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory)
```

But make sure the path is valid.

Or

you may also use

```
File.Exists();
Directory.Exists();
```